# How to execute code only in debug mode in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I have an ASP.NET web application and I have some code that I want to execute only in the debug version. How to do this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
#if DEBUG
your code
#endif
```

You could also add [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) to method that is to be executed only when you build it in debug mode:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void SomeMethod()
{
}
```

Comment: how does it knows that it's in debug, is it taking it from web.config ?

Comment: @Omu: I added the link to MSDN  - it explains there how the compiler selectively removes calls to methods marked `Conditional`.

Comment: You choose the build mode between release or debug. #if and Conditional  are used at compile time. Some more details: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/237540-conditional-debug-if-debug. You will find a lot information about in google.

Comment: @Omu: the `DEBUG` in `#if DEBUG` and `Conditional("DEBUG")` is defined as a command-line switch to the C# compiler.

Comment: Bear in mind the above all happens at compile time, based on build configuration. If you need to check in Razor scripts, inline code, or you need the behaviour to change when you change "debug" in your web.config, then you should be using @dtb's answer.

Answer (score 64):

[Detecting ASP.NET Debug mode](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/10228.aspx)

```
if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
    // this is executed only in the debug version
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled.aspx):

> *HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled Property*
>
> Gets a value indicating whether the current HTTP request is in debug mode.

Comment: It's just `if (HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled)` in MVC 5.

Answer (score 11):

I declared a property in my base page, or you can declare it in any static class you have in applicaition:

```
    public static bool IsDebug
    {
        get
        {
            bool debug = false;
#if DEBUG
            debug = true;
#endif
            return debug;
        }
    }
```

Then to achieve your desire do:

```
    if (IsDebug)
    {
        //Your code
    }
    else 
    {
        //not debug mode
    }
```

Comment: I guess you meant 
#if DEBUG
            debug = true;
#endif

Comment: debug will be initialized to false by default, so you IsDebug method will always return false, are u missing the bool debug = true?

Comment: Local variables are **not** initialized to anything, so the current revision doesn't compile in release mode.