# Visual Studio and .net, any way to perform an action in code - only if debugging?

Tags: .net, debugging

I'm aware of the #debug directives, but this is used when you are compiling code in debug mode.

Is there a way to detect if the code is being debugged using standard .net debuggers and create some logic around this?

for example

```
if (isDebugging)
{
  //change value of variable
}
```

thanks in advance.

EDIT : Failing this I guess the next logical approach would to build a plugin, but I'm just checking the obvious / easier route first.

Comment: if (Debugger.IsAttached) looks like it could work.

Comment: if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) ? c# http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/252477-debug-mode , cheerios!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to execute code only in debug mode in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734741/how-to-execute-code-only-in-debug-mode-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugger.IsAttached did the trick.