# How can I set up my application to reliably write logging data to a log file without slowing it down?

Tags: vb.net, logging

I am writing a VB.NET application in which I need to have logging to a .log file next to application executable where every line has a time stamp, and the name of the function/code block that is being executed. I have a Sub in my application which handles writing to a file:

```
Imports System.IO
    Sub addToLog(contents As String)
       If Not File.Exists(logPath) Then createNewLog()
       Dim textToWrite = "[" & Date.Now & "] " & contents & vbNewLine
       File.AppendAllText(logPath, textToWrite)
    End Sub
```

(Every function that calls this Sub specifies it's name through reflection in the Contents variable).

However, I was soon to discover that this method slows down my application a lot, because there are lots of functions being executed that need to be logged, and addToLog call takes at least 10ms.

I thought that I could take a different approach - create a global String variable, and write logging data to that global variable instead. When the application is exited, another Sub is called to write the contents of that global variable into a .log file all at once. Problem is, if the application crashes, the data would be lost, which defeats the whole purpose. So I thought I would add the call to write Sub to the MyApplication_UnhandledException Sub in the Application Events. The idea is that the write to file Sub would still execute even if the application crashes. However, something tells me that this is not a very fool-proof way, and there could still be some instances where the contents of that global variable would not be written into the .log file if application crashes in some unexpected way.

Can someone advise if there are faster and more reliable logging methods than the one I described? I know there are logging libraries for VB.NET, but I want to learn how this is done.

Comment: There's also the reflection part that can slow things. Maybe you could enable this feature with a compile time variable. It would only be access if needed. You could reduce the amount of concatenation but that might just be micro optimization. Finding a way to remove File.Exists would also help.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Lotus. I can avoid reflection by writing out the names of functions manually. Could you specify a little more about compile time variable? How exactly would I use it here? See, I want to log everything, not just errors that occur, so in case the error does occur, I can see everything that happened in my application since it was launched in that log.

Comment: You could [call the method in debug only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734741/how-to-execute-code-only-in-debug-mode-in-asp-net) since it might not be a good idea to do it in production. You could always try writing in the event viewer.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I do need this specifically for production. I need my application generating a log so that if my clients have my application crash, the application can send the entire log back to me so I can determine what caused it, and fix the problem.